# Are there any languages besides English of which teachers are commonly monolingual?

Tags: english, bilingualism, education-statistics

Many teachers of English are monolingual in this language. In job postings, it is seldom required that they be at all conversational in the language of the country where they are to be employed. If the teacher descriptions on Italki are any indication, all teachers of other languages besides English are at least bilingual. Are there any confirmed exceptions?

Comment: The title asks for "commonly", while the body question asks for "any exceptions". Any response to the title question also answers the body question, but not vice versa. Which are you interested in? Or maybe you would like to ask how common the monolingualism is?

Comment: @Tommi I disagree. My observations that English teachers are commonly monolingual and that teachers of other languages never are are not mutually exclusive propositions. Basically, I want to know what proportion of Spanish teachers only know Spanish, what proportion of Mandarin teachers only know Mandarin, and so on. Speaking to your experience in Scandinavia, how easy would it be to find a Swedish/Danish/Norwegian teacher who didn't speak English if one wanted to learn through immersion from the very beginning?

Comment: I would expect all local qualified language teachers to know other language(s), but maybe some old ones would not? Though they would probably know at least German, too. I think all of them have studied foreign languages in school, at the very least.

Comment: @Tommi I know quite a few English teachers who lived abroad for decades without ever learning the local language. Of course, this might have more to do with the hegemony of English than anything else.